# Good design of a Haskell data structure modeling a statistical test

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I want to define a simple data structure that contains basic information and results of a statistical test. Each test contains a name and a result. There are multiple options to choose from and I can't get my head around about what choice would be good. Some intro code:

```
type Calculation a = Either Failed a
data Failed = NoVariance | NotEnoughData | ...

type Name = String
type P = Double
```

And examples with pros and cons:

```
data Test = Test Name (Calculation P)
```

Pros: It's probably the simplest data structure - **each** test contains a name and a P value

Cons: There is no type safety. An ANOVA would be considered the same as KruskalWallisH

```
data ANOVA = ANOVA Name (Calculation P)
data KruskallWallisH = KruskallWallisH Name (Calculation P)
```

Pros: We have type safety now.

Cons: Name has to be manually put everywhere. If in the future I'd have 15 tests and a new field was required for all of them (say, Description), 15 edits would have to be made instead of 1 in the simple case above

```
data Test a = Test Name a
data ANOVA = ANOVA (Calculation P)
data KruskallWallisH = KruskallWallisH (Calculation P)
```

Pros: This solves the Name problem. Also, now different tests can contain more than just a single *(Calculation P)* result. For example, *Pearson* would contain a *(Calculation P)* and a *(Calculation R)*

Cons: It also introduces a second test type into play. Having Test declared in Test.hs and ANOVA declared in ANOVA.hs makes it sort of not obvious that ANOVA has a name, unless the constructor function is also in ANOVA.hs:

```
anova = Test $ "ANOVA" $ ANOVA $ anovaCalc...
```

We could try a type-class:

```
class HasName a where
  nameFrom :: a -> Name

data ANOVA = ANOVA (Calculation P)

instace HasName ANOVA where
  nameFrom _ = "ANOVA"
```

Pros: now the instance for the name sits next to the data structure

Cons: we have lost the Test type entirely. *Test ANOVA* simply reads much better than just *ANOVA*

At this point I'm a little lost with how to proceed. Is there a rule-of-thumb or some good practices I could follow?

Comment: could you not create a data type to hold the "type" of test you're doing (ANOVA etc - apologies I'm not a statistician so these are a bit meaningless to me), and add that as a parameter to your `Test` type: `data Test = Test Type Name (Calculation P)`. This seems to me to give you all the advantages of the first method while adding type safety for your different types of test. [PS this is just off the top of my head, I am no expert on this and haven't written production code in Haskell, so apologies if this isn't right for some reason]

Comment: @RobinZigmond What would the type of `Type` be?

Comment: I mean it would be your own type. `data Type = ANOVA | KruskallWallisH | ...`

Comment: I see. I'm afraid this wouldn't much type safer than `data Test = Test Name (Calculation P)` since all of the test results have different meanings and they are hardly interchangeable. This approach would still happily compile and let me pass ANOVA to something that should use KruskallWallisH.

Comment: Why not `type Test = (String, Calculation Double)`? After all you said  "Each test contains a name and a result.".

Comment: @Elmex80s This would loose type safety - ANOVA could be passed where only KruskallWallisH would make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Elmex80s The type would be the same for different tests and not all tests are interchangeable. Test like ANOVA and KruskallWallisH are an example of such a case. Their results mean different things and the tests should be applied in different scenarios.

Comment: I think not much people understand those tests, but if you want to define different tests in Haskell then do something like `data Test = ANOVA | KruskallWallisH | ...` just like mentioned in one of the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix the last two options:

```
newtype Test a = Test a

class HasName a where
  nameFrom :: proxy a -> Name

-- ANOVA.hs

newtype ANOVA = ANOVA (Calculation P)
instance HasName ANOVA where
  nameFrom _ = "ANOVA"
```

So you can now write `Test ANOVA`, if that looks better, and get the name via `nameFrom :: Test ANOVA -> Name`.

Comment: This is a new approach for me - thanks. Does proxy have a kind :: * -> * ?

Comment: It does in standard Haskell. With PolyKinds it has kind `k -> *` for whatever the kind `k` of `a` is, and `ANOVA` has kind `*`, so in the instance it still has `* -> *`.